# Is an empty complexType valid in an XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XML schema which I need to process and in the middle of it there is this line:

```
<xsd:complexType name="SomeName"/>
```

Is this valid XSD schema, or should a `complexType` always have some kind of content (child elements, attributes, anything)?

Comment: The XSD is valid .. is only this the question?

Comment: @Xstian - more or less, yes. I'm writing a tool that needs to process an XSD and this construct crashes it at the moment. It's rather meaningless in the context, but I could simply ignore it. The underlying question was - should the bug be fixed in the source of the XSD (it's automatically generated and there are many other bugs in that software), or in my processor.

Comment: This construct meaning that in your XML could be a tag `</SomeName>` or `<SomeName><SomeName/>` without characters inside. For any other question feel free to ask.

Comment: To the "closer": in which aspect is it "primarily opinion-based", exactly? This is a very specific and correct technical question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is valid.

See the [schema](http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd) for the schema.

```
 <xs:complexType name="complexType" abstract="true">
  <xs:complexContent>
   <xs:extension base="xs:annotated">
    <xs:group ref="xs:complexTypeModel"/>
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:NCName"/>
    <xs:attribute name="mixed" type="xs:boolean" use="optional" default="false"/>
    <xs:attribute name="abstract" type="xs:boolean" use="optional" default="false"/>
    <xs:attribute name="final" type="xs:derivationSet"/>
    <xs:attribute name="block" type="xs:derivationSet"/>
   </xs:extension>
  </xs:complexContent>
 </xs:complexType>

 <xs:group name="complexTypeModel">
  <xs:choice>
      <xs:element ref="xs:simpleContent"/>
      <xs:element ref="xs:complexContent"/>
      <xs:sequence>
       <xs:group ref="xs:typeDefParticle" minOccurs="0"/>
       <xs:group ref="xs:attrDecls"/>
      </xs:sequence>
  </xs:choice>
 </xs:group>

 <xs:group name="attrDecls">
  <xs:sequence>
   <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element name="attribute" type="xs:attribute"/>
    <xs:element name="attributeGroup" type="xs:attributeGroupRef"/>
   </xs:choice>
   <xs:element ref="xs:anyAttribute" minOccurs="0"/>
  </xs:sequence>
 </xs:group>
```

So the minimum would be:

```
<xs:complexType name="someNCName"/>
```

Which is the case in your question.

Comment: Fair enough. Thank you! :)

Comment: Hmm, as long as we're at it - is `<element />` also valid? And what does that even mean?

Comment: Yup. Absolutely valid. Element with an empty content. Semantics can be very different. One possible usage would be analogous to the "marker interface" in OOP. Or recall the HTML `<br/>` element.

Comment: But even a `<br/>` element requires a name! This is... totally anonymous. How would this even look like in an XML? Does it mean that the element can have whatever name it wants?

Comment: Then I did not understood correctly what you meant by `<element />`. Please post another question with the schema construct. I am not quite sure, what you mean here, sorry.

Comment: There you go. Answer for another 25 points of rep. :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26844136/is-an-empty-element-valid-in-xsd

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is a perfectly valid 'empty element'.  Often used as a 'flag'.  Take a look at http://www.w3schools.com/schema/schema_complex_empty.asp.  That example includes a type with an attribute, but the discussion is valid.

[EDIT - new URL] https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_complex_empty.asp