# Is an empty element valid in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd

Continuing my [XSD questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26842045/is-an-empty-complextype-valid-in-an-xsd) for today:

In an XSD document, is the following:

```
<element />
```

a valid construct? That is, it's an element which does not have a name, type, anything. Totally anonymous.

And if this is a valid XSD, what does that mean? How would such an element appear in the XML?

Comment: The question is more interesting than it may first appear, and certainly should not be closed and moved to Superuser per the ill-advised close vote currently issued.  See my [**answer below**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26844253/290085).

Comment: I also strongly disagree with the close request. Why is it supposed to be on `general computing hardware and software`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on where it is placed.

In `xs:appInfo` or `xs:documentation` (and few other constructs) anything may be valid.

Next this element:

```
<element />
```

Does not specify the namespace. So it is either in a wrong namespace or there's a `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"` somewhere in the context.

Assuming the latter this may be a global (`topLevelElement`) or a local (`localElement`) element definition.

It is invalid in both cases:

- Global element must have a `name` attribute.
- Local element must have have a `name` or a `ref` attribute. I think that just according the [schema](http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema.xsd) of the schema it might be syntactically valid, but there [are restrictions in the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#d0e4233):

> 2 If the item's parent is not , then all of the following must be true:
>
> 2.1 One of ref or name must be present, but not both.

Answer (score 1):

### No, the `@name` attribute must appear in a global XSD element declaration.

See [**3.3.2 XML Representation of Element Declaration Schema Components**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#declare-element), including where it states (emphasis added):

> Note that the above allows for two levels of defaulting for
>   unspecified type definitions. An `<element>` with no referenced or
>   included type definition will correspond to an element declaration
>   which has the same type definition as the head of its substitution
>   group if it identifies one, otherwise the ·ur-type definition·. ***This
>   has the important consequence that the minimum valid element
>   declaration, that is, one with only a name attribute and no contents,
>   is also (nearly) the most general***, validating any combination of text
>   and element content and allowing any attributes, and providing for
>   recursive validation where possible.

Consider using [**wildcards**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#Wildcards) such as `xs:any` if you wish to allow any element.  Note, however, that you'll at least need to name a root element.

Comment: "No, the @name attribute must appear in an XSD element declaration." True for the top-level elements, but not true for local elements and few other minor exceptions.